# share kit two result variables; both claim instance variable in .m file

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sharekit

My question pertains to share kit's code. Sharekit was created a while back and i guess they can't keep up with bugs or something. i haven't gotten it working yet but i think it would be a great thing if it worked as anticipated. I'm just going through the code fixing errors, hoping i can get it running. This is in the files SHKRequest.h and SHKRequest.m. There are two instances of the same variable, result, and when the variable is synthesized in the .m file, it gives me the following error:

synthesized properties 'result' and 'result' both claim instance variable 'result'

I'm kind of a little bit new to Objective-C (I've been doing it professionally for about 5 months now) and i have no idea what this error means or how to fix it. I understand there are two variables with the same name but i don't know WHY the developers put two in the code and i don't want to remove one unless i know it's not actually needed. So, can anybody give me some advice on this? here's the code that's causing the error:

.h file

```
@interface SHKRequest : NSObject  {
    NSURL *url;
    NSString *params;
    NSString *method;
    NSDictionary *headerFields;

    id delegate;
    SEL isFinishedSelector;

    NSURLConnection *connection;

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSDictionary *headers;

    NSMutableData *data;
    NSString *result;                 // This is the first instance of result
    BOOL success;
}

@property (retain, getter=getResult, setter=setResult:) NSString *result;
        // Second instance of result
```

.m file

```
@implementation SHKRequest

@synthesize url, params, method, headerFields;
@synthesize delegate, isFinishedSelector;
@synthesize data, result, headers, response, connection;
@synthesize success;
@synthesize result;                                        // result synthesized
```

Comment: There are two lines trying to synthesize `result`. Remove the redundant call to `@synthesize result;`.

Comment: Where did you find this code? The version at https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/Core/Helpers/SHKRequest.m is quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
@synthesize data, result, headers, response, connection;
@synthesize result;
```

Remove the 2nd line since there is no need to synthesize `result` twice.

Comment: thank you so much. i didn't even notice that. how did this library get so popular with a simple syntax error so crippling? very nice library though

Comment: I have no idea. I suggest you point out this problem to the developers of ShareKit.

Comment: when i downloaded sharekit and put it in my project, 80+ errors popped up, including but not limited to syntax errors and deprecation errors. i fixed all of the errors, as well as a couple small bugs that it had. i emailed the creator of sharekit the version of sharekit that i fixed, but i dont think hes interested in the project anymore. now its being supported by developers on github. my  version works with ios 7. the latest release was only supported up to ios 5. so if anybody wants my copy, email me. blaine.anderson@gmail.com.